# ref parameter on likes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-like

What I am trying to do is track click throughs of individual users likes and shares. This is easy with a unique link or when using Like, using the ref parameter.

What I do now is show the like button on a certain page, with the ref parameter set so I track any click through's on that link.

But this has a problem or a bug, if you use ref and click the like button then ref will show up on the like post on fb and I can track this. BUT if you also leave a comment when you click the like button, then the link is shared but the ref parameter is not on that link anymore!!

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Rob

Comment: add another parameter `myref`.

Comment: This is the code that I use:
<div class="fb-like" ref="xxxx" data-ref="xxxx" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-action="like" data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
So I am not sure how myref would work?